# Android delete hidden folder (".FOLDERNAME") programatically

Tags: android

My app contains a hidden folder in SD card. I want to delete that folder when my condition (first time run) comes true.

Here is my code

File path to hidden folder

```
 private static final String SET_START_DIRECTORY = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/.MYFOLDER/";
```

Method

```
    private void checkReinstallApp(){
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("FIRSTRUN", 0);
    boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true);

    if (firstRun) {
        Log.w("activity", "first time");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
        editor.commit();
        File f = new File( SET_START_DIRECTORY);
        f.delete();

        DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(WebViewActivity.this);
        db.deleteAllDownloads();
    } else {
        Log.w("activity", "second time");

    }
}
```

File f returns true for this code

```
 if(f.exists())
        {
          Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this,"exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

But folder still on the SD card and cannot be deleted from this peace of code.What should i change?

Comment: probably `MYFOLDER ` contains other files or folder so use recursive deletion

Comment: yes..it contains files

Answer (score 0):

I have used recursive deletion as ρяσѕρєя K suggest and now folder can be delete.
Recursive delete method can be found on here.
[android-delete-folder-recursively](http://www.maheshchari.com/android-delete-folder-recursively/)

```
public static boolean deleteFile(File file) {
if (file != null) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
    String[] children = file.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        boolean success = deleteFile(new File(file, children[i]));
        if (!success) {
        return false;
        }
    }
    }
    return file.delete();
}
return false;
}
```